# I Can't See the Data on the Other Page When I Pressed the Button on the Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval, repeater

I list the products on the table using the repeater. I put a button to update the pictures of the products. When the button is clicked, it goes to the update page.

**This is my update button inside the repeater:**

```
<asp:Label ID="LblProductID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
<asp:LinkButton ID="BtnUpdateImage" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm blue" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' OnCommand="OnUpdateImage"><i class="fa fa-image"></i> Update Image</asp:LinkButton>
```

**And this is my button's code:**

```
protected void OnUpdateImage(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Session["ID"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

    DataRow dr = function.GetDataRow("SELECT ProductImage FROM tbl_Product WHERE ID = '" + Session["ID"] + "'");
    if (dr != null)
    {
        Session["ProductImage"] = dr["ProductImage"].ToString();
        Response.Redirect(Page.ResolveUrl("update-product-image.aspx"));
    }
}
```

**And this is my update-product-image.aspx code:**

```
<asp:Image ID="ProductImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Uploads/ProductImages/"+Eval("ProductImage") %>' Height="500" Width="500" />
```

But this page does not show the picture. Where do I make mistakes?

Comment: What is Eval("ProductImage") supposed to be within your product-image page? Did you mean to fetch it from the session? If you're already putting the ID into the session, why do you need to put the productimage in there too? you can even just put the ID on the querystring of the product-image page and use it that way, then product-image page can get the data from the database. Bit more web-friendly, bit less dependency between the pages

Comment: where is onclick of your button in aspx?